# Django: Queryset filtering based on min max set in another table

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Consider the following models:

```
Class ExamResults:
   ...
   Marks = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
   Course = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
   Academic_year = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

Class ExamSetting:
   ...
   GradeAThreshold = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
   GradeBThreshold = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
   ...
   Course = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
   Academic_year = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

Now I have an API to search/get results from ExamResults for all students. The API works fine and I use Q filters to filters the results. For e.g.

```
...
year_contains = self.request.GET.get("year_contains", "")
if year_contains:
      q_filt |= Q(Academic_year__icontains=year_contains)
      
queryset = queryset.filter(q_filt)

...
```

Now I have a requirement to filter the queryset for the following condition:

1. List of exam results where the Marks exceed GradeAthreshold
2. List of exam results where the Marks are less than GradeAthreshold and exceed GradeBThreshold and so on

What would be the best way of doing this? The `ExamResults` table and `ExamSetting` has two common fields which can narrow down the thresholds. For e.g. I use the below code in serializer to check if the result has Grade A or not:

```
setting = ExamSetting.objects.filter(Academic_year=obj.Academic_year, Course=obj.Course, is_active=True).first()
if obj.Marks >= setting.GradeAThreshold:
   # Grade A
...
```

This does work and I do get the results with grades. Now how do I add something like this in the queryset so that I can filter the results for Grade A or B results?.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned `ExamSetting` and `ExamResult` both have common fields; assuming proper data integrity, you can pivot based on one of those.

For example, if you want all exam results with grade A or above for a similar course:

```
setting = ExamSetting.objects.filter(
    Academic_year=obj.Academic_year, 
    Course=obj.Course, 
    is_active=True
    ).first()

query = Q(Course=setting.Course) & Q(Mark__gte=setting.GradeAThreshold)
ExamResults.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Since I am creating a queryset, the `obj` won't have the `Academic_year` or `Course`.

Comment: `setting` is an instance of `ExamSetting`. The return value for `ExamResults.objects.filter(query)` is a queryset. I don't know what `obj` is in this context.

Comment: I am trying to return a query set which then be passed to the serializer which will have access to the “obj”. I want to limit the number of rows passed to serializer by adding filter

Comment: From what I'm understanding now, you want to use `obj`'s attributes to filter `setting` when you don't have access to it. Unless you create some kind of relationship between them I don't see how you can achieve that.